# Rails transfer form data modification error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form in which I input a transfer. This transfer is stored into a database (and used for a transaction in the controller).

It worked roughly, but now for the finetuning the input needs modification before I save or a transaction is made.

- The name of the recipient needs to be a transformed into this users id.
- The amount has a two decimal number input and should be modified to cents by multiplying it by a hundred and making it an integer. Banks need a solid integer basis as you know.

I thought this could work:

**Transfer model**

```ruby
  #transfer.rb
  has_one :sender,
          :class_name => "User", 
          :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_one :recipient, 
          :class_name => "User", 
          :foreign_key => "recipient_id"

  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :recipient_id, presence: true
  validates :amount, numericality: {:greater_than => 0}

  before_validation :recipient_name_to_id 
  before_validation :amount_to_cents

  def recipient_name_to_id
    recipient = User.find_by_user_name(self.recipient_id)
    self.recipient_id = recipient.id
  end

  def amount_to_cents
    cents = self.amount
    cents = cents*100
    cents.to_i
    self.amount = cents 
  end
```

To modify the :recipient_id and the :amount taken from the form while the app asks for a name and any number.

It doesn't work, because in the transaction it can't find the recipients banksaldo.

**NoMethodError in TransfersController#create**

**undefined method `cents' for nil:NilClass**

```ruby
 @account_b.cents += @transfer.amount
```

Everything else works fine. I checked it thoroughly.

But maybe it helps to add the controller

**TransfersController**

```ruby
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #transfer
    @transfer = Transfer.new(transfer_params)
    @transfer.sender_id = @user.id

    #transactie tussen accounts
    @account_a = @user.account
    @account_b = Account.find_by_user_id(@transfer.recipient_id)
      if @account_a != @account_b
        if @account_a.cents >= @transfer.amount
          Account.transaction do
              @account_a.cents -= @transfer.amount
              @account_a.save!
              @account_b.cents += @transfer.amount
              @account_b.save!
              @transfer.save!
              flash.notice = "Uw opdracht is verzonden."
          end
        else
          flash.notice = "U beschikt niet over voldoende saldo om uw opdracht te doen slagen."
        end
      else
        flash.notice = "U kunt geen geld overmaken naar uw eigen account."
      end
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  private
  def transfer_params
    params.require(:transfer).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id, :amount)
  end
```

**Update**

I am now working with current setting (is this more clever, or does it not really matter?).

```ruby
#same transfer.rb model but now with this as non private methods.
def recipient_id=(value)
  user = User.find_by_user_name(value)
  self[:recipient_id] = user.id 
end

def amount=(value)
  cents = value * 100
  cents.to_i
  self[:amount] = cents
end
```

The code now gives:

**Validation failed: Amount is not a number**

and can't @transfer.save! in the controller.

**Update 2**

All right it nearly works. I had to make the value into a float first by to_f. Then it worked... until I turned on the validation again (which I commented out) and now it gives an error that amount is not an integer... Which I state in the def. Hmprff :S

**Update 3**

It all works now. My methods look like this now:

```ruby
  def recipient_id=(value)
    user = User.find_by_user_name(value)
    self[:recipient_id] = user.id 
  end

  def amount=(value)
    cents = value.to_f * 100
    self[:amount] = cents.to_i
  end
```

Bad thing about it is that with wrong form information the app gives it's validation error screen, while I want it to give a notice and redirect it to the show window where it was.

It can't find both methods flash and redirect in these methods I defined above in the transfermodel.

Comment: You're up to 5 separate problems, which is going to get your question flagged as unclear or too broad. It's time to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Link back to this one if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

`@account_b` did not load, either because `transfer_params[:recipient_id]` is `nil` or because no `Account` exists with that ID. You might consider switching to `Account.where(user_id: @transfer.recipient_id).first!` so that it raises an exception, or you need to check whether `@account_b.nil?` and handle the problem. Because `@account_a != nil`, your logic continues through until you can't access `@account_b.cents`.

Check your form and incoming parameters to make sure `params[:transfer][:recipient_id]` is present, and then verify that user ID has an `Account`.

Comment: I seem to be really stuck with my validation and number changing. It gives me "Validation failed: Amount is not a number" and when I comment this out it works but 50.50 becomes 0.50 cents. So the def amount=(value) is not working... While the other def recipient_id=(value) does it's job perfectly.

Comment: You should ask new questions separately so this one remains simple and understandable. Look into `has_one` instead of writing your own `recipient_id=`. `to_i` doesn't change your variable, it returns a new integer.

Comment: Hmm, well everything works now, but it's not pretty when you give the form wrong information. The app comes with it's screen of validation errors, which are correct, but I'd rather sent the user a neat flash notice. Coding a flash notice in these object model methods gives the error that I use a method it can't find. The same when I use a redirect. Flash notice and redirects don't work in these methods.